# get url data via get method

Tags: magento-1.7, phtml

How can i get a param from my url??

> ?access_token=Atza|IQEBLjAsAhR6-eMBCha6N7pV6bZ3i1Z3kv2IrgIUfOwQ_NUK0yf4e4Cb3lWsqA91zrmc7JRnwtNtQH1U433_A9odU1QF6O-RR4hHPuU5_1i1XZZyg7Sk_P0hs6cLzMaLQzaZ0JZtYhWsoCWBDu8Piuu3AHq8wu4mPQdTFaaCvT4tP-gHPBFu5Cu5uPbrPli-VOYo51sWSRFEWYFpzypjxkU4Ti-Y8bzFjcHo6RYJF6jXvIE8a4ZVG-5bX2k9ftjvsJQQsOsywh8ir3wJkVm9I-rG_RfuGf_OiCwZ5pbn63k0161Gwr4Phv0TaUjBV-UaCfBjFP7eiBwmKL53hPPYiUFakRmHKctVp1PodOMo83y1ovuX7XZfQujmWHrvkJmfDOgjiuqxOLnGhK_xCbu09hFNLwMvcV15E19OQ_247S68j2c9nSLDVeH1HKOGzxsgeQnNFfIMzTmOPNx8zThQeD5upjDFbxfrIDGNZeApJWWUVgfJLkbnvdAem_K1qeQNAnWp8IwRgoWWr7wNip5Dm5LXA64z4vQsT_NkykoOdFWE943Pd1nGOIAbcTe_AEdsjuibZ3azJ4TfVVPtgG8J9KMcxxe6npnb35sMI-kqOgDb3J4&token_type=bearer&expires_in=3600&scope=profile
>   payments%3Awidget payments%3Ashipping_address

I want to get access token data on my `phtml` page!

I used `<?php echo $this->getRequest()->getParam('access_token');?>` but not wroking for `access_token`

How can get that??

Comment: $accessToken = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('access_token');

Comment: If it doesn't work, I'm guessing you're looking at the wrong template.

Comment: This code work for me! As i see that access_token was encoded on a array.

 `   $amazon_data = json_decode($_REQUEST['amazon_Login_state_cache']);
    access_token = $amazon_data->access_token;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code work for me! As i see that access_token was encoded on a array.

```
$amazon_data = json_decode($_REQUEST['amazon_Login_state_cache']);
access_token = $amazon_data->access_token;
```

Thank you all for sharing your knowledge

Answer (score 3):

in magento way

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('access_token');
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('token_type');
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('expires_in');
```

in simple php

```
$_GET['access_token'];
$_GET['token_type'];
$_GET['expires_in'];
```

for access token

```
$url=parse_url(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl());

$fragment = $url['fragment'];

$access_token = preg_replace('/&token_type=(.*)/',"",$fragment);
```

Comment: This not returning anything! I already tried this

Comment: `expires_in` is working but `access_token` not working! any idea??

Comment: `$params = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();  print_r($params);` try that and see param are listed?

Comment: `Array ( [token_type] => bearer [expires_in] => 3600 [scope] => profile payments:widget payments:shipping_address )` this is what i get

Comment: i added the solution for getting the access_token follow that

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge. When i `print` the `$_REQUEST` i see that it generating an array with json encode. after that i solved it using `$amazon_data = json_decode($_REQUEST['amazon_Login_state_cache']);access_token = $amazon_data->access_token;`

Answer (score 2):

Use below code:

```
echo Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParam('access_token');
```

as well as you can also try this

```
echo Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('access_token');
```

Third one:

```
echo $this->getRequest()->getParam('access_token');
```

Comment: Not working for `access_token`

Comment: Its working for me .I think there is other issue, If you post your code full URL may be it helps to identify error

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge. When i `print` the `$_REQUEST` i see that it generating an array with json encode. after that i solved it using `$amazon_data = json_decode($_REQUEST['amazon_Login_state_cache']);access_token = $amazon_data->access_token;`

Answer (score 1):

Try simple solution in the your template:

```
<?php echo $this->getRequest()->getParam('access_token');?>
```

So, I test it and it works:
Code:
[image: Code]
Url without params:
[image: Url without params]
Url with params:
[image: Url with params]

> http://magento17.uchuhlebov.web.ra/customer/account/login/?access_token=Atza|IQEBLjAsAhR6-eMBCha6N7pV6bZ3i1Z3kv2IrgIUfOwQ_NUK0yf4e4Cb3lWsqA91zrmc7JRnwtNtQH1U433_A9odU1QF6O-RR4hHPuU5_1i1XZZyg7Sk_P0hs6cLzMaLQzaZ0JZtYhWsoCWBDu8Piuu3AHq8wu4mPQdTFaaCvT4tP-gHPBFu5Cu5uPbrPli-VOYo51sWSRFEWYFpzypjxkU4Ti-Y8bzFjcHo6RYJF6jXvIE8a4ZVG-5bX2k9ftjvsJQQsOsywh8ir3wJkVm9I-rG_RfuGf_OiCwZ5pbn63k0161Gwr4Phv0TaUjBV-UaCfBjFP7eiBwmKL53hPPYiUFakRmHKctVp1PodOMo83y1ovuX7XZfQujmWHrvkJmfDOgjiuqxOLnGhK_xCbu09hFNLwMvcV15E19OQ_247S68j2c9nSLDVeH1HKOGzxsgeQnNFfIMzTmOPNx8zThQeD5upjDFbxfrIDGNZeApJWWUVgfJLkbnvdAem_K1qeQNAnWp8IwRgoWWr7wNip5Dm5LXA64z4vQsT_NkykoOdFWE943Pd1nGOIAbcTe_AEdsjuibZ3azJ4TfVVPtgG8J9KMcxxe6npnb35sMI-kqOgDb3J4&token_type=bearer&expires_in=3600&scope=profile%20payments%3Awidget%20payments%3Ashipping_address

Comment: @QaisarSatti You have really checked it? `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` has the public method `getRequest()`

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge. When i `print` the `$_REQUEST` i see that it generating an array with json encode. after that i solved it using `$amazon_data = json_decode($_REQUEST['amazon_Login_state_cache']);access_token = $amazon_data->access_token;`